# Render all routes/templates in one page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having an ember.js app with multiple (nested and not nested) routes, just like a usual ember app.

What I want: **Export multiple templates as pdf**

For this to achieve, I wanted to **render all the needed templates in one page** (template) and then use js.pdf to export.

Is it possible to render all my "pages" to a single page?

For Example, my app

- app
- app/start
- app/items
- app/items/1
- app/items/2

Desired result

- app/allpages --> render start, items, items/1, items/2 in one page among themselves.

What i tried with no luck:

- iframes --> not working in js.pdf
- renderTemplate function
- named templates and other ember stuff

Thanks!

Comment: iframes should work, actually. what didn't work about using them?

Comment: also, what's js.pdf? iframes should work with browser's print functionality

Comment: It's just a library to create pdfs with js: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

Comment: iframes work with browser's print functionality but not with this library because of cors problems

Comment: is there another way without iframes in ember.js to render different routes in one template?

Comment: it's probably easier to fix your CORS problem (configurable on your backend / server side)

Comment: Wrap all of your  routes in seperate components and In the route where you want to render all the routes invoke the components that you have used for the routes.